# Print only elements of array

Tags: java, android, arrays

i'm new in Java/Android. I create an array like this:

```
String [] resultArray = new String [lengthFromServ];
                int i = 0;      
                while (i<lengthFromServ) {
                    int result = fromServ.read();
                    char valueOfResult = (char) result;
                    String resultFromServ = Character.toString(valueOfResult);
                    resultArray[i] = resultFromServ;
                    i++;
                }
```

lengthFromServ is declared before:(while statement executes 4 times)

```
lengthFromServ = 4;
```

Serwer send me string: "0,12"

When I try print elements of this array by:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray))
```

I get:

```
[0, ,, 1, 2]
```

My question is: how can I get only elements of this array ? Without `"["`, `"]"`, `","` ? I just want to get this string:

```
0,12
```

Please help, I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What are you using the values of `resultArray` for besides printing them out?

Comment: This value, for example 0,12 is only for print, to show user in textview and send string "0,12" to another activity by Bundle

Comment: Just use an `ArrayList` and save yourself a lot of trouble

Comment: The string `0,12` has 4 chars and `Arrays.toString()` is displaying the same, with `,` as delimiter . What is your expectation?

Comment: How is `fromServ` defined?

Comment: fromServ is defined:                                            fromServ = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading totally the wrong way from the server. You should use a BufferedReader or a DataInputStream. These will allow you to read easily:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int lengthFromServer = 4;
byte resultArray[] = new byte[lengthFromServer];
dis.readFully(result);
String result = new String(resultArray);
```

Or, if your server will add a newline after the content you can do it more easily:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String result = dis.readLine();
```

Comment: I have to read it not by buffereReader. Server is written in LabVIEW so if i want to read data immediately i can't read it by buffer.

Comment: DataInputStream doesn't use a buffer. But BufferedReader doesn't stall  your program in order to read from the socket, I think.

Comment: Thank You, this solution is good to me, but on the other hand the solution by Joni is good too in my case, so thanky You both.

Comment: I'v got one more question about Your answer - how you define result in dis.readFully(result) ?

Comment: It will fill `result` with the upcoming bytes of the stream. `readFully` will force the buffer `result` being filled completely. So if your buffer is `n` bytes long, it will be forced to read `n` bytes into that buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String resultArrayString = Arrays.toString(resultArray);
System.out.println(resultArrayString.substring(1, resultArrayString.length()-1).replace(" ", "");
```

My answer is based on the assumption that your primary purpose is simply to print out the array in your desired format.

Comment: Yes, i editted my commecnt later. Your answer could be good but later i have to do something with String 0,12